# Why does this variable disappear in a struct?

Tags: ruby, struct

Maybe I just don't know enough about structs and have been using them blindly but the result below seems irrational to me.

```
class VarTest < Struct.new(:email)
  def perform
    puts "Start: #{email}"
    if email == "nothing"
      email = "bad email"
    end
    puts "End: #{email}"
  end
end
VarTest.new("test@example.com").perform
```

**Unexpected Output:**

```
Start: test@example.com
End:
```

**If I change the code to:**

```
class VarTest < Struct.new(:email)
  def perform
    e = email
    puts "Start: #{e}"
    if e == "nothing"
      e = "bad email"
    end
    puts "End: #{e}"
  end
end

VarTest.new("test@example.com").perform
```

**We get the expected output:**

```
Start: test@example.com
End: test@example.com
```

Can someone please explain what is going on with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual goal? In other words, why are you using inheritance instead of just `VarTest = Struct.new(:email)` then `VarTest.new('an@email.ohai')`?

Comment: It's being used by delayed job as part of the enqueue.  Regardless, why does using it this way cause this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace `email = "bad email"` with `self.email = "bad email"` it will work as expected.  This is always true when using setters.

The reason is simple: when Ruby encounters a bareword, it tries to resolve it as a local var. If there is none, it will try to call a method by that name. Inside the class body self is the implicit receiver, so readers just work. Now for the writer there's a problem. If you write something like `foo = "bar"`, Ruby will create a new local variable, hence you need to make the receiver explicit.

This case is a bit trickier: `if email == "nothing"` uses the getter. However, `email = "bad email"` is still seen by the parser and a local variable `email` will be set to `nil`. This always happens when the parser sees a bareword as the LHS of an assignment. This local `nil` value is what makes it seem like the value of `email` disappears (which you can verify by only changing the last `puts` to `puts "End: #{self.email}"`).

Comment: awesome.  so this isn't unique to Structs. I didn't realize that's how   Struct variables worked.  Makes perfect sense in hindsight.  Well, the learning continues and that's what makes this stuff fun!  Thanks!